# Run specific @BeforeClass only when starting unit tests in debug mode?

Tags: java, unit-testing, debugging, logging, testng

I have implemented a simple unit-test in TestNG to test a message exchange.
When I'm debugging the test I want to run all loggers (java.util.logging) to run with the log-level `FINEST`. In order to achieve this, I have defined a `@BeforeClass`method which switches all loggers to the intended log-level.
Is there any possibility to automatically enable the fine-grained-Loggers when starting the java-vm in debug mode (via IntelliJ). I thought about influencing the `enabled`-property of the `BeforeClass`-Annotation, but have no idea whether and how this is possible.

```
@BeforeClass(enabled = false)
    public void beforeClass()
    {
        Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        for (Handler h : rootLogger.getHandlers()) {
            h.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()` to know whether you are in debug mode in runtime, and set log level accordingly.

In intelliJ, the following code:

```
System.out.println("TEST: " + 
    ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments());
```

Prints the following output in debug mode:

> TEST:
>   [-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:40770,suspend=y,server=n,
>   -ea, -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576, -javaagent:/opt/idea-IC-181.4203.550/plugins/Groovy/lib/agent/gragent.jar,
>   -javaagent:/opt/idea-IC-181.4203.550/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar=file:/tmp/capture.props,
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]

and the following output in non-debug mode:

> TEST: [-ea, -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576,
>   -javaagent:/opt/idea-IC-181.4203.550/lib/idea_rt.jar=46442:/opt/idea-IC-181.4203.550/bin,
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]